# extract audio objective -c

Tags: objective-c, audio

I'm having difficulty finding the apple documentation that I need.

What I want to do is extract a certain amount of audio samples from a certain position in an mp3 and store that pcm data in an array.

Could somebody point me in the right direction for the suitable api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for [Core Audio](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: In addition I found "ExtendedAudioFile" which on the face of it allows you to extract a certain amount of samples from a specified position.